# How to handle interaction between objects at the same level

Tags: javascript

I am designing a website that uses lots of javascript for controlling what happens on the page. Each part of the webpage (map, listings panel, etc) has an associated javascript object. I have some questions on the best practices for handling the communication between these objects.

Here is a simplified version: Imagine a website where there is a google map plus markers on one side of the page and on the LHS there is a list with details for each of the markers. See image below.

When you click on a marker, the associated details will be highlighted on the LHS panel, and if you click on the details, the corresponding map marker will animate for a bit.

[image: example of the website]

The way I was thinking of doing it was to have each object call the other object's method via the top-level rather than directly (ie so that each object just reports the event and lets the top-level decide what to do). See the diagram and code below...

[image: objects interraction]

```js
//Class to construct and operate the google map and its markers etc
function MainMap(){
    var me = this;

    me.createMapMarkers = function()
        ....
        /* clickedMapMarker is called but not defined within this class */
        me.clickedMapMarker(); 
        ....
    }

    me.bounceMarker = function(marker){ /* code to animate the marker */ }

    ...
}


//Class to handle the construction and operation of the list items 
function ListingsPanel(){
    var me = this;

    me.createListItems = function()
        ....
        me.clickedListLink(item);
        ....
    }

    me.highlightItem = function(item){ /* code to highlight */ }

    ...
}


//Instantiate the objects
theMainMap = new MainMap();
theListingsPanel = new ListingsPanel();


//Wiring between the objects
theMainMap.clickedMapMarker = theListingPanel.highlightItem;

theListingPanel.clickedListLink = function(item){
    theMainMap.bounceMarker(item);
    ...
}
```

My questions are:

1) Does this kind of design scheme have a name?

2) What is the name for things like `clickedMapMarker()` - is this an event handler?

3) Am I right to wire up the interaction at the top-level?

4) Or is there a better way for this kind of task (inc any links explaining alternatives)?